# Is there a difference between WebOS LevelDB and Google LevelDB?

Tags: webos, leveldb

Is there a difference between [WebOS LevelDB](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/hp-news/press-release.html?id=1164460) and [Google LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/)?

Are these two independent projects or is WebOS LevelDB only a integration of Google's database into WebOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, WebOS is using Google's LevelDB: http://www.webosnation.com/hp-s-open-source-webos-roadmap